# Function returns a string as a rvalue

Tags: c++11

I am a new C++ beginner. I don't understand why the expression

```
string three() { return "kittens"; }
```

returns an rvalue. Is it because of the returned string(kittens) a temporary value? Thank you so much

Comment: Technically what you posted is not an expression, lvalue, or rvalue; it's a function definition.  But given that definition, the expression `three()` would be an rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is constructing a temporary string object using the basic (C-style) string literal in your return statement, and returning that as a temporary value. Whoever calls your function will either have to copy the temporary rvalue into an lvalue, or it will be discarded at the end of the statement.

Or to be more precise, the compiler is being helpful by automatically calling std::string's conversion constructor to turn your string (a `const char*`) into a string, making your code more or less equivalent to `return std::string("kittens")`.

[Here is a short (but useful) primer on the difference between lvalues and rvalues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx)